# Magento2.3.3 add to cart button doesn't redirect to cart after adding in cart

Tags: magento2, addtocart, magento2.3.3

I'm facing a weird issue after upgrading from magento 2.2.3 to 2.3.3.

When adding to cart from product page, I've enabled setting **After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart** to **Yes**.

After the product is added to cart, under function **Magento_Catalog/js/catalog-add-to-cart::ajaxComplete** doesn't go to success, while it goes to error.

The data coming under **res.responseText** has string with value **"cart add{"backUrl":"https://m232.test/checkout/cart/"}"**.

I'm guessing that's due to the invalid response I got because **cart add** is added to the response but not sure how. Has anyone faced the same issue?

Comment: Did you checked your store config setting store vise ? If you have multiple stores then please check that once.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure but let's check this

Go to

> Stores -> configuration -> Under sales tab -> checkout

under **shopping cart** section on the right side, check

> After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart -> NO

If that is yes then it must to redirecting to cart page after adding the product to cart.

Hope this helps